# Drupal 7 - How do I get Drupal to recognize my HTML template?

Tags: drupal-7

I have been studying all I can on how to integrate an HTML template into Drupal but I have not had great success. The simple theme I am experimenting with is in this link:

http://pixelhint.com/minima-free-html5-minimalist-website/

When it comes to plugging the template into Drupal, I can get as far as writing the .info file. But I do not understand what to do from there.

I realize that this could be a lot to ask, but if it's possible for someone to just give me some clear pointers as to what modifications I should make after creating the .info file, I would be very grateful!

P.S. If this is too much to ask, please tell me, and I will try to make even more specific requests.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

This contains whole..

[Templating](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

[More](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)..